# Converting openstruct array to json

Tags: json, ruby

I have 2 openstruct arrays of the form :

```
<OpenStruct id=0, name="EMGEE CABLES AND COMMUNICATIONS LIMITED", group=3>
<OpenStruct id=1, name="ELECTRICAL TECHNOLOGY PARK OF INDIA", group=2>
<OpenStruct id=2, name="PRISM BUILDCON PRIVATE LIMITED", group=2>
....
```

and

```
<OpenStruct source=79, target=3, value=5>
<OpenStruct source=80, target=0, value=5>
<OpenStruct source=81, target=0, value=5>
....
```

My objective is to convert this data into json format and save the result to a file in the following form :

```
{
  nodes:
   [
     {id=0, name="EMGEE CABLES AND COMMUNICATIONS LIMITED", group=3},
     {id=0, name="ELECTRICAL TECHNOLOGY PARK OF INDIA", group=3},
     {id=0, name="PRISM BUILDCON PRIVATE LIMITED", group=3}
   ]
  links:
   [
     {source=79, target=3, value=5},
     {source=80, target=0, value=5},
     {source=81, target=0, value=5}
   ]

}
```

Comment: Did you try to write it by yourself? What kind of problem did you encountered, if so? Share your code so we could give you more precise tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you would overwrite the .to_json method to your liking in your structs.

Alternatively the [.to_h method on OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html#method-i-to_h) does pretty much what you want. So `.to_h.to_json` should also achieve your goal.

And if your question is how to achieve the desired output in general you could go about like this:

```
the_json = {
  nodes: your_first_array_of_structs.map(&:to_h),
  links: your_second_array_of_structs.map(&:to_h)

}.to_json
File.open('path/to/file.json, 'w') { |file| file.write(the_json) }
```

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer as accepted or clarify if you need more help, so that future visitors know if this issue has been resolved for you ;)